# Usage neural network in android project

Tags: java, android, neural-network

I want to use neuroph library in my android project. But when i run project, i received an error.

Error Type: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

```
`
NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork;
try {
  InputStream is = getAssets().open("or_perceptron.nnet");
  neuralNetwork = NeuralNetwork.load(is);
  neuralNetwork.setInput(1, 1);
  neuralNetwork.calculate();
  double[] networkOutput = neuralNetwork.getOutput();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }`
```

i copied neuroph-core-2.8.jar file in libs folder in workspace, then i clicked "Add Build Path". But i receive an error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The library is not compatible with Android because it requires Java 1.7 as stated directly on their [download page](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/download.html). You might be able to edit the source code and compile with Java 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with that particular library. Normally, that type of error indicates that a dependency is missing from the build-path. Look on the website for whatever dependencies that the library requires.

Additionally, here is an excellent tutorial on Neural Networks in Java.

http://www.heatonresearch.com/articles/series/1